# Amazon + NGINX + SSL + IE8

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl

How hosting multiple SSL sites on a server that has a single IP number and the WindowsXP + IE8 see the correctly certificate?

Amazon EC2 allow to assign only one IP per server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a multi-domain (sometimes called "UCC" or "SAN") certificate.

Comodo's allows up to 100 domains on one certificate. We use that offering and it's worked well for us. IIRC, Namecheap just became a reseller of it (cheaper, usually).